# How do I handle Memcached::ServerIsMarkedDead error with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached

In my Rails app, I changed my model's find method to search into the cache before looking into the database, but I sometime get this error:

```
Memcached::ServerIsMarkedDead
```

While waiting for Memcached server to be up again, how should I handle this error and force Rails to search into the database?

Thank you,

Kevin

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just rescue the exception and search the database in that case.

`Rails.cache.fetch` encapsulates this pattern in a more generic way, and you may want to look into that instead of hacking `find`, which is likely to bite you soon when Rails 3 comes out.